# disable run task for specific scala version

Tags: sbt

Is there a way to disable or throw an exception for `run` task on specific scala version (let's assume for scala `2.10`, `run` task does not make sense, while for scala `2.11`, it's a valid task). I could implement this as logic inside my project/code, but if I would like to do it in sbt - what would be the way to go?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
val scalaVersionCheck = Def.task {
  if (scalaVersion.value.startsWith("2.10"))
    sys.error("wrong version") 
} 

run <<= run dependsOn scalaVersionCheck
```

Basically, define a task that does the version checking you need, throw an exception if it isn't correct, make the run task depend on this new task